# Limit with sinus function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How to compute these two limits $$\lim_{x \to 1}\sin\frac{1}{x-1}$$ and $$\lim_{x \to 1}(x-1) \sin \frac{1}{x-1}?$$ Squeeze theorem should do the thing but I do not know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first limit does not exist! Make substitution $u=\frac{1}{x-1}$, so when $x\to1\Rightarrow u\to\infty$ and:

$$\lim_{u\to \infty}\sin\left(u\right)=?$$

(It is not defined because the sine oscillates).

For the second limit,
$$\lim_{x\to 1}(x-1)\sin\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)$$
Make the substitution $u=\frac{1}{x-1}$, so when $x\to1\Rightarrow u\to\infty$ and:
$$\lim_{u\to \infty}\frac{\sin\left(u\right)}{u}$$
But $|\sin(u)|<1$, so
$$\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{-1}{u}\leq\lim_{u\to \infty}\frac{\sin\left(u\right)}{u}\leq\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{1}{u}$$
By the squeeze theorem, both leftmost and rightmost limits tend to zero, so
$$0\leq\lim_{u\to \infty}\frac{\sin\left(u\right)}{u}\leq0\Rightarrow\lim_{u\to \infty}\frac{\sin\left(u\right)}{u}=0$$

Answer (score 3):

1)

$\lim \limits_{x \to 1} \sin\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)=\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \sin(x)$

Which does not exist! (Its up to you to take two subsequences which do converge to different limit-points)

2)

$\lim \limits_{x \to 1} \left| (x-1)\sin\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)\right|=\lim \limits_{x \to 1} | (x-1) |\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)\right|\leq   \lim \limits_{x \to 1} | (x-1) |=0$